# Why MySQL gives me some result in aggregate function without group by statement

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

i've experienced something... weird? using an aggregate function WITHOUT group by statement (yes, i know i sould). I'm using mysql 5.5 in this moment.

I've use some example tables with the same structure as in my real situation, so example may be extrange, sorry.

### Let's explain.

I have three tables with some referencial integrity:

As you can imagine: both, parent, child and person, are FK from Persons table id.

```
- Persons - 
id      name
1       Anna
2       Ben
3       Charly
4       Dennis
5       Emma
6       Fiona
```

```
- Relationships -
parent  child
1       3
1       4
2       5
```

```
- Log -
person  date
1       2020-05-05
```

Anna has two childs, Charly and Dennis
Ben has one, Emma
Fiona hasn't
Only Anna has an entry on log table

### Let's party.

Find children id 3 name ONLY if number 6 is his parent (looking for Charly if is Fiona's son)

```
select P.name, R.child, R.parent
from Persons P
    join Relationships R on P.id = R.child
    left join Log L on L.person = P.id
where R.parent = 1
    and R.child = 3
```

No result shown, ok, that's what i expected because as we can see, there's no row that matches condition.

Adding an aggregate function and group by shows the same 0 results.

```
select P.name, R.child, R.parent, count(L.person) as N_Entries
from Persons P
    join Relationships R on P.id = R.child
    left join Log on L.person = P.id
where R.parent = 1
    and R.child = 3
group by P.id
```

BUT

if i remove the group by condition i expect the same result
if there're no result, then grouping *should* be unnecesary.

```
select P.name, R.child, R.parent, count(L.person) as N_Entries
from Persons P
    join Relationships R on P.id = R.child
    left join Log on L.person = P.id
where R.parent = 1
    and R.child = 3
```

```
name    child    parent   N_Entries
Charly  null     null     0
```

### Why does it returns something?

Thank you and sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Nothng weird about it please read manual. 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Hello again, if it groups every row, why am i getting only Charlys name? (or whatever person name i'm looking for). Why am i not getting any value in child or parent column?

Comment: Because someone over at MySQL HQ has a hard time distinguishing between a bug and a feature

Comment: Also, if i add a group_concat statement in name column, it returns null.
why not every name? why not only Charly's name?